Exercise generalizing (related to) Hölder's inequality
I came across this exercise and feel absolutely stuck:
Let $p, q, r \in (1, \infty]$ be such that $1/p + 1/q = 1 + 1/r$. Suppose that $F : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the property that the functions $x \mapsto F(x, \cdot)$ and $y \mapsto F(\cdot, y)$ belong to $L^p(\lambda^n)$ $\lambda^n$-a.e. in $y$ and $\lambda^n$-a.e. in $x$, respectively, and both have $p$-norm less than or equal to $C$, for some $C > 0$. For each function $f \in L^q(\lambda^n)$, the function $P(f)$ is defined pointwise for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ by
[
P(f)(x) := \int F(x, y) f(y) , d\lambda^n(y).
]
Assume $r \leq \infty$. Let $f \in L^q$ and define
$$
g(x) = \int _ {\mathbb{R^n}} |F(x,y) f(y)| dy.
$$
I am told to use Hölder's inequality appropriately to prove that
$$
g(x) ^r \leq C ^{r-p} \lVert f \rVert _ q ^{r-q} \int_\mathbb{R^n} |F(x,y)|^p |f(y)| ^q dy.
$$
Finally, I must show that $P(f)$ is bounded and calculate its norm.
The problem I encounter is the inequality. I have tried many combinations of exponents to fit, and use Hölder's inequality but I failed every time. The information about $F$ maybe suggests to try using Young's inequality.

This may be a nontrivial exercise. However, this forum is not for help with exercises.

While I don't think this exact inequality was proven there, my blog post about proving Young's inequality using Holder has some similar steps; maybe they are helpful as a reference.

Actually, it looks like this is exactly equation (7) of my blog post. So maybe the exponents listed in equation (6) will be helpful to you.
